# Making a Foreign Key to an option of two different classes in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

So, basically, I'm wondering if it's possible to make a ForiegnKey in Django potentially point to a choice of two objects. Not actually.

Eg:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    pass

class Truck(models.Model):
    pass

class NumberPlate(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Car or Truck)
```

I know in this example, there are much better ways I could format the car-truck distinction but in my actual code, there seems no alternative without making things more complex. I guess I could just create a 'numberplate' for cars and trucks but that adds unnecessary clutter to my code.

Is there a way to choose between two types of objects to point to or a way I could get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be best to use a [Generic Relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) a NumberPlate can then be attached to any content type e.g

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use model inheritance to achieve what you want:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    pass

class Truck(Car):
    pass

class NumberPlate(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

Comment: But then I inherit the other model... Kinda ruining the app, wasting resources, leading to errors later on if I don't fill it in or explicitly null...